# Laravel reset password, Class '\App\User' not found

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a reset password URI, and it is there and uses the Laravel built in reset password system, but when I test it, I get:

> FatalErrorException in EloquentUserProvider.php line 126: Class
>   '\App\User' not found

This is my config/auth.php:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Model
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "Eloquent" authentication driver, we need to know which
| Eloquent model should be used to retrieve your users. Of course, it
| is often just the "User" model but you may use whatever you like.
|
*/

'model' => App\User::class,
```

And this is is my app/Http/routes.php:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::post('register', 'RegisterController@register');

Route::post('resetpassword', 'Auth\PasswordController@postEmail');

Route::resource('api/authenticate', 'AuthenticateController', ['only' => ['index']]);
Route::post('api/authenticate', 'AuthenticateController@authenticate');

//All protected routes should go in this group
Route::group(['middleware' => 'isUserAuthed'], function () {
  Route::get('restricted', 'WelcomeController@welcome');
});
```

My User class is located at app/User.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                AuthorizableContract,
                                CanResetPasswordContract
{
use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = ['name', 'username', 'password', 'role', 'active', 'email'];

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? The documentation for this doesn't seem very clear to me.

Comment: Well, have you moved the default `User` model somewhere else? Be default, it's right under the `app` directory.

Comment: What do you have in `app/User.php`?

Comment: I've added it to the question above. It is located at app/User.php.

Answer (score 1):

Your file name should be `User.php` not `user.php`

Comment: Oh, sorry, it is app/User.php. That has been updated in the question now.

Answer (score 0):

\App\User should be able to be found by EloquentUserProvider

Have you tried running this command in your applications folder?

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: I've just done this and it gives the same error: Class '\App\User' not found

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `::class`

```
'model' => 'App\User',
```

Comment: I had tried that before, too. But I get this error: `[Sat Oct 24 23:30:15 2015] [error] [client 24.10.139.15] PHP Fatal error:  Undefined constant 'App\\User' in /home/ct.1.1/config/auth.php on line 31`

Comment: You probably forgot the single quotes.

Comment: This should not be the problem. The error states that \App\User class doesn't exist. It doesn't say that there is something wrong with `::class`.